# Building Documentation for Nested projects with CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm working on a project that contains other projects as libraries using git
submodules. These sub-projects are under active development as well, so the root
cmake file will run the sub-project cmake files as well.

Example Project Structure:

```
current_project/
    src/
    include/
    docs/
    libs/
        sub_module_1/
            src/
            include/
            docs/
        sub_module_2/
            src/
            include/
            docs/
        sub_module_3/
            src/
            include/
            docs/
    src/
```

The actual building portion works fine. In some of the sub projects, the custom target `docs` is used to
generate the documentation. Since there are multiple `docs` targets defined for each
subproject, cmake complains. I don't have control over the sub-projects, and
therefore cannot simply edit the cmake files for those. Is there a way to, without
editing the sub-projects (as the changes will be overwritten when I do a git
update), either have cmake combine all the commands for each sub-project and run all
of them, or have it generate a prefix (probably the project name) for the docs
target for each project?

Edit: I see that CMake has projects as a defined term. I'm not referring to cmake projects. When I am saying project, I am referring to libraries and programs that, while related, are independent of each other.

Comment: Note, all libraries are set as different (and unique) projects if that helps at all.

Comment: What about using `ExternalProject_Add` for submodules? See, e.g., [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457920/embedding-one-cmake-project-inside-of-another).